# How to achieve clipper in horizontal? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[I'm trying to make a custom card by using the Clipper widget as the image shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMyJa.jpg)

But i was able to get the shape only on the vertical sides

```
 Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    double x = 0;
    double y = size.height;
    double yControlPoint = size.height * .95;
    double increment = size.width / 12;

    while (x < size.width) {
      path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x + increment / 2, yControlPoint, x + increment, y);
      x += increment;
    }


    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    while (x > 0) {
      path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x - increment / 2, size.height * .05, x - increment, 0);
      x -= increment;
    }

    path.close();
    return path;
```

Comment: waves? so you need waves or a [perforation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforation) shape?

Comment: my mistake, i need shape